# Should We use a Windows Service or Thread Pool?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-services

We're developing a web application in Asp.Net MVC 4 intended for hundreds of users.

We need to have a background service **per user** to work in an interval of a few minutes.

We are not sure whether to use `Windows Services` (multiple windows services) or to use a Thread Pool of processes. We think of Windows Services cause they're maintainable easily via windows server and that approach can save the overhead of programming a UI and manage threads. It also can easily run in an interval of time.

Is it possible for a `Windows Service` to automatically initiate a new instance for a new user who has just signed up (so we have multiple background windows services instances, one for each user)? if not the `Windows Services` option falls.

If the upper is possible, should We choose `Windows Services` approach or make our own managed `Thread Pool` of processes?

Comment: "Thread Pool of processes" doesn't really mean anything. Can you clarify?

Comment: Why does each new user need its own service? That is major overhead for no reason.

Comment: We are talking about architecture generally. I intentionally leave it vague. I need a general approach answer here. Between Windows Services and threads.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Funny, first you ask why each user needs its own service (as it's not clear) and then claim it's a major overhead for *no reason* yet he hasn't even told you the reason yet ;)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Each customer has it's own db and our support team needs to have control over each customer. So we can stop it's specific background service or other actions.

Comment: @DGibbs u made me laugh :)

Comment: Well, you're right. I should of probably said *it seems* instead if *is* :), anyway, how many customers are you expecting?

Comment: at least few hundreds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, starting a process per user guarantees you high memory overhead and non-scalability when you get into the 1000s. I don't see what starting a process (as opposed to a thread) could possibly save because the new process will contain at least one thread. Also, Windows Services have nothing to do with "logged in users". They are not made for multi-instancing.

[You seem to want to run background work in ASP.NET MVC.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) Be aware, that this is hard. Using *one* Windows Service can make sense here.

The hard thing about background work is that worker processes can exit for many reasons. You *must* tolerate this. A service has the same problem: You need to deploy new versions and restart the server regularly. You also need an HA strategy so you need multiple servers.

I'm not convinced that a Windows Service would be a better choice even for long-running background work.

With 100s of concurrent background workers you should probably use async IO to not have 100s of threads dedicated.

I assume your background work waits most of the time. You can make the waiting async (using a timer) and all the rest synchronous. That gives you a simple implementation and vast savings in memory usage.

Comment: when saying "starting a process per user guarantees you high memory overhead", by saying "process" you mean for Windows Service specifically right? and, can you plz shed more light on using waiting async? what do you mean that all the rest are synchronous? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That goes for any process. A service does not have a lot of additional overhead to starting up a new process (and the CLR!).

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate service to perform background tasks might introduce additional burden:

1. Having two separate apps will certainly increase complexity of your project: if you need any communication between the web app and the service, it will be more complex (and slower) than having the whole thing inside the web app. You also need to deploy two separate projects, so there some plumbing overhead that will double this way.
2. Performance wise, there is nothing you gain from this approach. On the contrary, having your own managed pool inside the web app will allow better scheduling of these threads and quite possibly allow you to run them more efficiently than simply letting Windows take care of this. You really don't want to spawn hundreds of processes (or threads) which would compete for resources simultaneously on the same machine.
3. If nothing else, keeping the whole functionality inside the web app app might simplify your hosting options. Installing and managing a Windows service might require more privileges than a cheap hosting provider is prepared to give you.

Having said that, running background tasks in ASP.NET means that you need to be prepared to have your threads aborted abruptly, due to exceptions, recycling or any other reason IIS can think of. Running these background tasks in a separate process will certainly be less susceptible to these ASP.NET quirks, so it ultimately boils down to a compromise: how important it is for you to make sure these tasks are never interrupted, and does it justify additional programming and maintenance effort?

**[Edit]**

If your concern is how to schedule these tasks inside the service, take a look at some scheduling libraries for .NET, like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). It allows better control over scheduling than simply using a timer and (should you ever need them) provides some advanced features like persisting jobs (useful if you want to make sure your jobs will finish after restarts) and clustering for large scale applications.

Using a simple timer will work, but make sure that you understand how each of .NET timers dispatches its events.

Comment: @ilanS: It seems that [@usr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24487110/69809) also got the idea that you want to run the task inside ASP.NET. I am not sure what was the question then?  If you already know you will have a separate app, then go for a windows service, that's a no brainer. But obviously a single windows service which will manage all background jobs; you need to have control over thread scheduling, there is no point in having hundreds of db connections and hundreds of separate processes running simultaneously.

Comment: Tnx @Groo. I think I would go for a windows service managing threads. Should I use a thread pool inside the Windows Service or manually initiating threads? and about the 'hundreds of db connections you've mentioned' - What choice do I have? take in account each customer has it's own db... But you know what, that would be a problem because I need our support team to be able to stop / start specific customer's background task.

Comment: If you're talking about the .NET `ThreadPool` vs creating a new `Thread`, then it usually depends on the duration of your tasks. CLR `ThreadPool` (`Task` uses it by default also) is suited for short-lived jobs as it's used by the entire runtime. On the other hand, you may be talking about your own managed pool of threads, which also makes sense. It all depends on the nature of these tasks. Do they finish quickly? In that use the `ThreadPool` or `Task`s as they've been optimized to reduce contention.

Comment: No. These services need to work all the time. These are XML services which are live and work on the customer DB all the time.

Comment: I decided to go with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396645/timer-within-thread-within-windows-service?rq=1

Comment: @ilanS: that looks like a sensible approach. But a couple of remarks: first, this implies that your jobs don't "work all the time", but they are instead started using a timer in regular intervals. Second, the answer you linked deals with the scheduling part of your problem, which is not what your question is really about. Third, be aware that using a `System.Timers.Timer` implicitly uses the `ThreadPool` to dispatch your tasks, and, what's more importantly, allow the same event handler to be started simultaneously (it must be reentrant).

Comment: If your tasks take longer to finish than the timer interval, `Timer` will happily dispatch new events on different `ThreadPool` threads, and soon you will either have an enormous queue of tasks waiting to start (if you are locking your handler), or a bunch of threads running the same task simultaneously. Or, you can disable [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) and restart the timer manually whenever you're done. If scheduling is your concern, then you might consider using an existing library for that.

Comment: `@Groo`, If I want a winform GUI application to manage the tasks (I use Timers.Timer processes) which the Windows Service activates, how would I communicate between the Winform application and the Windows Service? Tnx in advance...

Comment: Probably using WCF, but you should ask a new question (or [simply search StackOverflow for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+service+gui+communication) because yours will probably end up closed being a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a open-source project, [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com), to handle this type of workload. It uses a Windows Service to manage the task scheduling, but leverages your existing ASP.NET MVC application to handle the action out-of-band. Tasks can be in the hundreds of thousands and are persisted until successfully dispatched.

Here is a simple workflow diagram:

```
user initiated action
        |
        |           ......................
        |           :  future callback   :
        V           V                    :
======================       ===========================
|   Your web app     |       | Revalee Windows Service |
|                    |       |                         |
======================       ===========================
        |                                ^
        |    registers a callback now    |
        |________________________________|
```